# How to include pagination in section-iterate?

Tags: moqui

Thanks a lot for spending your precious time in answering my questions and I am back again with another question.
I am using  in xml using xsd 1.4. It gives me the option of paginate and paginate-size but it does not working as it does in case form-list. So could please let me know the reason for this behavior and also how to get pagination in section-iterate using xsd 1.5.
Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the XSD there is also a comment that it is not yet implemented. To make this more clear I've commented out those attributes altogether (this change is now in the moqui/moqui GitHub repo).

What is it that you want to use these for? I put the attribute definitions in there a long time ago as a possibly useful feature, but never implemented it because I haven't found a good use for it yet... and not sure there is one.

Answer (score 0):

As of the moment you can paginate with

`<section-iterate ... paginate="true">...</section-iterate>`

controlling pagination size is not yet implemented